# Querying contacts in android using Contacts, ContactsContract

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to query contacts using `ContentResolver` in android. There are multiple options to query like `contacts`, `ContactsContract`, `CommonDataKinds`, etc. But unable to decide advantages over each other.  Please help me out in differentiating with each other and which one to use when.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all have to do with android versions, like

`android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI` - this only works for Android `2.0 (SDK level 5) and higher.` On older versions of Android, we need to stick with the original `android.provider.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` .

And `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds` is Container for definitions of common data types stored in the ContactsContract.Data table. If you want to know more check [this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.html)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped you, you can also up vote it :D

Comment: :) what's difference between ContactsContract and Contacts?

Comment: Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html